# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPictures' of undefined cordova

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins

I trying to use the plugin cordova-plugin-imagepicker, but the chrome console returns:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPictures' of undefined cordova*.

Tested with chrome remote tools in a Samsung J7 Prime.

Here is the code:

```
$("#btn_pic").on('tap',function(e) {
    window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function(results) {
       for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
       }
    }, function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }, {
      maximumImagesCount: 10,
    }); 
});     

<a type="button" id="btn_pic">Button</a>
```

Pd: Really don't know if i used right way this plugin. I try with this steps (with cordova plugin ls this plugin seems ok added):
 1. cordova add ...
 2. Write the code in page
The question in this point is: Is missing some call like

```
<script src="includes/imagepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or not neccesary?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it neccesary agree a response to my own question, but my solution for this problem was change the plugin because my android version not give me explicit permissions. 
Now, i use this: 
https://github.com/mirulumam/cordova-imagePicker